# Spring Data Elasticsearch - No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.time.Instant]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

When pulling a document from an elasticsearch (7.6.2) index with the use of `spring-data-elasticsearch` (4.0.0.RELEASE) I get:

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.time.Instant]
```

I tried using ElasticsearchRepository:

```
Contact indexedContact = contactElasticRepository.findById(someId).orElse(null);
```

```
package com.example.mail.elastic;

import com.example.mail.model.Contact;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface ContactElasticRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Contact, String> {

}
```

Or issuing a query directly like this:

```
public Contact findById(String id) {
        Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("id", id)).build();

        SearchHits<Contact> contacts = elasticsearchTemplate.search(searchQuery, Contact.class, IndexCoordinates.of("mail"));
        return contacts.getSearchHit(0).getContent();
}
```

Both approaches have the same result with the problem above.

My model is defined like this:

```
package com.example.mail.model;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
@Document(indexName="mail", type="contact")
public class Contact {   
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 255)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 255)
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 255)
    private String displayName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Lob
    private String note;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="contact", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Photo> photos =  new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

   // ...getters and setters
}
```

Note that the model uses @Entity and @Document at the same time.

I cannot find any examples or documentation about additional mapping configuration or libraries needed.

Comment: Please see this documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping

Comment: Do you have any field with type `java.time.Instant`?

Comment: the error does not match your entity class. In your index you have a field of type long and in your entity there is a corresponding property of type `java.time.Instant`.  But this is not in the `Contact` class you show.

Comment: It amazes me that I haven't searched for the most obvious thing first - the Contact entity's relationship - User extended an abstract class that held timestamp properties which were of type java.time.Instant, a simple change to java.util.Date which also does the job well enough solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch is able to handle the `java.time` classes, you have to annotate the corresponding property with the `@Field` annotation setting the correct type and format.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this unanswered question with the same issue, which I managed to solve after a few hours, so I'll answer. According to [Spring Data Elasticserach documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping), you need to annotate an Instant property with @Field:

```java
@Field(type = FieldType.Date)
private Instant createdDate;
```

This should be enough because SDE doesn't use Jackson anymore but instead a *MappingElasticsearchConverter* (I mention this because other answers recommend using Jackson's @JsonProperty). With this annotation, a converter is automatically created for this property and used.

In case you use a **custom date format**, take into account that [starting from Elasticsearch 7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/migrate-to-java-time.html#java-time-migration-incompatible-date-formats) you should't use `yyyy` but `uuuu`. e.g:

```java
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
private Instant lastModifiedDate;
```

Last but not least, the whole index should be wiped for these changes to work.

**Edit:**
You must specify a `format` for `FieldType.Date`, either one of the predefined or a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

ES 7.14

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = {}, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd")
private LocalDate birthday;

@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = {}, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime updateTime;
```